# remove /admin in admin panel url of django project and access to pdf file in browser

Tags: python, django, file, pdf, django-admin

Good Day!

I can not acces to a uploaded file in browser through admin panel, after removing /admin in urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('', admin.site.urls),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

files are kept in /media/ which is shown in setting.py of project

```
#STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
import os
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

file model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django import forms


class Store(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code+" "+self.name
    


class Scale(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class Thermometer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    

class Status(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
 

class Measurement(models.Model):
    stores = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    scales = models.ManyToManyField(Scale, through='ScaleMeasurement')
    thermometers = models.ManyToManyField(Thermometer, through='ThermometerMeasurement')

    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.stores.code+" "+self.stores.name
        
    def clean(self):
        # Check if a Measurement with the same stores' code and name exists
        if Measurement.objects.exclude(pk=self.pk).filter(stores__code=self.stores.code, stores__name=self.stores.name).exists():
            raise ValidationError({"stores": ["A Measurement with the same stores' code and name already exists. Please use a different combination."]})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()  
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    


class ScaleMeasurement(models.Model):
    measurement = models.ForeignKey(Measurement, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    scale = models.ForeignKey(Scale, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    scale_no = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    audit_starting = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    audit_ending = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    certificate_id = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    audit_certificate = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    store_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    pdf_content = models.FileField(
        #upload_to='pdf_documents/',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['pdf'])],  # Validate only PDF files
        verbose_name=_('PDF')
    )
    archived = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    @property
    def filename(self):
       name = self.pdf_content.name.split("/")[1].replace('_',' ').replace('-',' ')
       return name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('myapp:document-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
    
    def __str__(self):
        return ''
        
    def update_store_code(self):
        if self.measurement and self.measurement.stores:
            self.store_code = self.measurement.stores.code+" "+self.measurement.stores.name
            print(self.store_code)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.update_store_code()  
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        
    def archive(self):
        self.archived = True
        self.save(update_fields=['archived'])

    def unarchive(self):
        self.archived = False
        self.save(update_fields=['archived'])



class ThermometerMeasurement(models.Model):
    measurement = models.ForeignKey(Measurement, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    thermometer = models.ForeignKey(Thermometer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    thermometr_no = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    audit_starting = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    audit_ending = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    certificate_id = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    audit_certificate = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    store_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    pdf_content = models.FileField(
        #upload_to='pdf_documents/',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['pdf'])],  # Validate only PDF files
        verbose_name=_('PDF')
    )
    archived = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return ''
    
    def update_store_code(self):
        if self.measurement and self.measurement.stores:
            self.store_code = self.measurement.stores.code+" "+self.measurement.stores.name
            print(self.store_code)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.update_store_code()  
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def archive(self):
        self.archived = True
        self.save(update_fields=['archived'])

    def unarchive(self):
        self.archived = False
        self.save(update_fields=['archived'])
```

file admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from openpyxl import Workbook
from django.http import HttpResponse

class ReadOnlyAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReadOnlyAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = kwargs.get('instance')
        if instance and instance.pk:
            archived = instance.archived
            for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
                if field_name != 'archived' and isinstance(field, forms.fields.Field):
                    field.disabled = False
                    if archived:  # Disable 'thermometer' and 'status' fields in archived rows
                        if field_name in ['scale', 
                                          'scale_no', 
                                          'thermometer', 
                                          'status', 
                                          'thermometer', 
                                          'thermometr_no', 
                                          'model', 
                                          'audit_starting', 
                                          'audit_ending', 
                                          'certificate_id', 
                                          'audit_certificate', 
                                          'status', 
                                          'archived', 
                                          'pdf_content']:
                            field.disabled = True
                if field_name == 'archived':
                    make_read_only = archived

class ScaleMeasurementInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ScaleMeasurement
    form = ReadOnlyAdminForm
    extra = 0
    fields = ('scale', 'scale_no', 'model', 'audit_starting', 'audit_ending', 'certificate_id', 'audit_certificate', 'status', 'archived', 'pdf_content')
    exclude = ['store_code']
    list_filter = ('archived',)
    
    def archive_button(self, obj):
        if obj.archived:
            return 'Unarchive'
        return 'Archive'

    archive_button.short_description = 'Archive/Unarchive'
    archive_button.allow_tags = True

    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super().get_actions(request)
        if 'delete_selected' in actions:
            del actions['delete_selected']
        return actions

    def archive_selected(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(archived=True)

    archive_selected.short_description = "Archive selected items"

    def unarchive_selected(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(archived=False)

    unarchive_selected.short_description = "Unarchive selected items"

    actions = ['archive_selected', 'unarchive_selected']

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        if obj and isinstance(obj, ThermometerMeasurement) and obj.archived:
            for field in form.base_fields.values():
                field.disabled = True
        return form

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj and isinstance(obj, ThermometerMeasurement) and obj.archived:
            return [field.name for field in self.model._meta.fields if field.name != 'archived']
        return super().get_readonly_fields(request, obj)

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        field = super().formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
        if db_field.name in ['scale', 'scale_no', 'model', 'audit_starting', 'audit_ending', 'certificate_id', 'audit_certificate', 'status', 'pdf_content']:
            field.widget.attrs['style'] = 'width: 100px;'
        return field
        

class ThermometerMeasurementInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ThermometerMeasurement
    form = ReadOnlyAdminForm
    extra = 0
    fields = ('thermometer', 'thermometr_no', 'model', 'audit_starting', 'audit_ending', 'certificate_id', 'audit_certificate', 'status', 'archived', 'pdf_content')
    exclude = ['store_code']
    list_filter = ('archived',)  # Filter by archived status

    
    def archive_button(self, obj):
        if obj.archived:
            return 'Unarchive'
        return 'Archive'

    archive_button.short_description = 'Archive/Unarchive'
    archive_button.allow_tags = True

    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super().get_actions(request)
        if 'delete_selected' in actions:
            del actions['delete_selected']
        return actions

    def archive_selected(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(archived=True)

    archive_selected.short_description = "Archive selected items"

    def unarchive_selected(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(archived=False)

    unarchive_selected.short_description = "Unarchive selected items"

    actions = ['archive_selected', 'unarchive_selected']

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        if obj and isinstance(obj, ThermometerMeasurement) and obj.archived:
            for field in form.base_fields.values():
                field.disabled = True
        return form

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj and isinstance(obj, ThermometerMeasurement) and obj.archived:
            return [field.name for field in self.model._meta.fields if field.name != 'archived']
        return super().get_readonly_fields(request, obj)
    
    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        field = super().formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
        if db_field.name in ['thermometer', 'thermometr_no', 'model', 'audit_starting', 'audit_ending', 'certificate_id', 'audit_certificate', 'status', 'pdf_content']:
            field.widget.attrs['style'] = 'width: 100px;'
        return field



class StoreAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['name', 'code']
    
    
    def code_and_name(self, obj):
        return f"{obj.code} {obj.name}"
    
    code_and_name.short_description = "Магазины"
    list_display = ('code_and_name',)

class MeasurementAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ScaleMeasurementInline, ThermometerMeasurementInline]
    list_display = ('measurement_name', 'count_scales', 'count_thermometers')
    autocomplete_fields = ['stores']

    def measurement_name(self, obj):
        return str(obj)



    def count_scales(self, obj):
        scales = Scale.objects.all()
        scale_counts = [obj.scalemeasurement_set.filter(scale=scale).count() for scale in scales]
        scales_info = "<br>".join([f'<span style="display: inline-block; width: 120px; text-align: left; margin-right: 5px;">{scale.name}:</span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 50px; text-align: right;">{count}</span>' for scale, count in zip(scales, scale_counts)])
        return mark_safe(f'<div style="white-space: pre-line;">{scales_info}</div>')


    def count_thermometers(self, obj):
        thermometers = Thermometer.objects.all()
        thermometer_counts = [obj.thermometermeasurement_set.filter(thermometer=thermometer).count() for thermometer in thermometers]
        thermometers_info = "<br>".join([f'<span style="display: inline-block; width: 300px; text-align: left; margin-right: 5px;">{thermometer.name}:</span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 50px; text-align: right;">{count}</span>' for thermometer, count in zip(thermometers, thermometer_counts)])
        return mark_safe(f'<div style="white-space: pre-line;">{thermometers_info}</div>')



    def download_statistics(self, request, queryset):
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="statistics.xlsx"'

        workbook = Workbook()
        worksheet = workbook.active
        worksheet.title = 'Statistics'

        # Fetch headers for scales and thermometers from their respective models
        scale_headers = [scale.name for scale in Scale.objects.all()]
        thermometer_headers = [thermometer.name for thermometer in Thermometer.objects.all()]

        # Add the certificate column header
        # certificate_header = 'Certificate Link'

        # Create a dictionary to store statistics for each store
        store_statistics = {}

        # Collect statistics for each store in the queryset
        for measurement in queryset.all():
            store_code = measurement.stores.code
            if store_code not in store_statistics:
                store_statistics[store_code] = {
                    'Store Name': measurement.stores.name,
                    **{header: 0 for header in scale_headers},
                    **{header: 0 for header in thermometer_headers},
                    # certificate_header: '',  # Initialize the certificate link field
                }

            # Collect scale statistics for the store
            scales_count = measurement.scales.values('name').annotate(count=models.Count('name'))
            for scale in scales_count:
                scale_name = scale['name']
                if scale_name in scale_headers:
                    store_statistics[store_code][scale_name] += scale['count']

            # Collect thermometer statistics for the store
            thermometers_count = measurement.thermometers.values('name').annotate(count=models.Count('name'))
            for thermometer in thermometers_count:
                thermometer_name = thermometer['name']
                if thermometer_name in thermometer_headers:
                    store_statistics[store_code][thermometer_name] += thermometer['count']

            # Add the absolute certificate link to the store statistics
            # if ScaleMeasurement.pdf_content:
            #     print(ScaleMeasurement.pdf_content)
            #     certificate_link = request.build_absolute_uri(ScaleMeasurement.pdf_content.url)
            #     store_statistics[store_code][certificate_header] = certificate_link

        # Create headers for the worksheet
        headers = ['Store Code', 'Store Name'] + scale_headers + thermometer_headers
        worksheet.append(headers)

        # Populate the worksheet with store statistics
        for store_code, stats in store_statistics.items():
            row = [store_code, stats['Store Name']] + [stats[header] for header in headers[2:]]
            worksheet.append(row)

        workbook.save(response)
        return response


    actions = [download_statistics]
    
    ##
    #??????????? ?????? ?????? ??????? (???????? ? LastName). ???? LastName ?? ????????????? StoreCode - ?? ???????????? ??? ???????
    ##
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request)
        last_name = request.user.last_name  
        
        if last_name:  
            # Filter measurements based on last name if a store code matches
            matching_stores = Store.objects.filter(code=last_name)
            if matching_stores.exists():
                queryset = queryset.filter(stores__code=last_name)
        
        return queryset

admin.site.register(Store, StoreAdmin)
admin.site.register(Scale)
admin.site.register(Thermometer)
admin.site.register(Status)
admin.site.register(Measurement, MeasurementAdmin)
```

Admin panel view url
[image]

If I try to open this file by clicking in browser it is not openening

[image]

it is showing this error on page

[image]

But if I return admin/ in urls.py as it was before, it is opening a file in browser

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

can anyone help on this please?

Comment: Please show the code for the model that contains the field that holds the pdf.

Comment: I have uploaded files

Comment: In the code above I don't see why it is not working. Do you have multiple urls.py files in your project? Please confirm that you have added `+= static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` and that you are running the app in DEBUG mode

Comment: I use only url.py which is in django project

Comment: += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) where I should add this

Comment: That has to be added to the `urlpatterns` in urls.py. Please confirm that option A) with `'admin/'` (working) and option B) without `'admin/'` (not working) have it added. Plus you need to run the project in DEBUG mode.